# Can't unlink Google AdWords customer account from test manager account

Tags: google-ads, accounts

I'm trying to unlink a customer account from my Google AdWords test manager account.

But got:

> Every account must have either a user with administrative access or a manager account with administrative ownership

How can I solve this?